# @Url.Content changes after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In My MVC3 Razor application I'm referring ajax in Layout page as

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I run this in my local machine,its working perfectly.. However after publishing using iis7, my ajax calls are not working. When i checked the View Source in browser, the reference is like `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` before publishing and `<script src="mvcapplication/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
 after publishing. I'm confused Why url gets changed ?

Answer (score 1):

`Url.Content(string contentPaht)` uses the `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string contentPath)` method to create an absolute url:

```
public string Content(string contentPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "contentPath");
    }
    if (contentPath[0] == '~')
    {
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(contentPath, 
               this.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
    }

    return contentPath;
}
```

As you can see the `Request.ApplicationPath` is used, which respresents the the Virtual Directory.
When the argument `contentPath` does not start with a `~` it returns the contentPath without using the `ToAbsolute(string contentPath)` method.

So you can try using:

```
@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
```

**Edit:** You can also try to change the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "NameVirtualDirectory/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: My all jquery $.ajax() calls has the url:/Controller/Action.. Since virtual directory name added after publishing, now the ajax call needs url:mvcapplication/Controller/Action.. How to solve this ?

Comment: You can try to change the default routing in the Global.asax, see my edit

Comment: I don't get it why you want do force the urls. If the app wohudl hcange from the virtual dir "mvcapplication" ot noather virtual dir, you have to modify every link in the app. You're generating ilnks from routes precisely to avoid this problem. I disagree with putting the virtual dir name into the route definition, it has no meaning for the app and you still have to change it when you deploy the app to another virtual dir.

Answer (score 0):

Because on the server the application has the virtual path "mvcapplication", that is the app resides in IIS in the virtual directory "mvcapplication". It has nothing to do with asp.net mvc, it's an IIS setting.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I would appreciate if you let me know the changes that i need to make in IIS to reflect the url.

Comment: Do you have full control over the server? Or at least are you sure there is no other app setup as / ? Usually an app is setup in a virtual directory because it can't be setup in the root ("/") .

Comment: My all jquery $.ajax() calls has the url:/Controller/Action.. Since virtual directory name added after publishing, now the ajax call needs url:mvcapplication/Controller/Action.. How to solve this ?